# How do you enable debugging on a Samsung Sidekick 4G (Froyo)?

Tags: android, debugging, adb, android-2.2-froyo

Trying to debug with a Samsung Sidekick 4G right out of the box gives:

> **Android AVD Error**
>
> No compatible targets were found.  Do you wish to add a new Android Virtual Device?

Settings doesn't have anything that looks like "Developer Options" as available in Ice Cream Sandwich/Jelly Bean where USB debugging can be enabled.  How do you enable debugging?

Is it like the Kindle Fire where you have to go put magic numbers in `~/.android/adb_usb.ini`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While formulating this question, I discovered the answer buried in [the manual](http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201111/20111103025047970/T839_English_User_Guide.pdf) of all places.  RTFM indeed:

[image: Android Development]

The upshot is that the relevant setting lives in **Applications** > **Development**.